# Line split is not functioning as intended

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, python-requests

I am trying to get this code to split one at a time, but it is not functioning as expected:

```
for line in text_line:
    one_line = line.split(' ',1)
    if len(one_line) > 1:
        acro = one_line[0].strip()
        meaning = one_line[1].strip()

        if acro in acronyms_dict:
            acronyms_dict[acro] = acronyms_dict[acro] + ', ' + meaning
        else:
            acronyms_dict[acro] = meaning
```

Comment: When I run this code, `acronyms_dict` has plenty of things in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `' '` from the `str.split`. The file is using tabs to delimit the acronyms:

```py
import requests

data_site = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/priscian/nlp/master/OpenNLP/models/coref/acronyms.txt"
)
text_line = data_site.text.split("\n")
acronyms_dict = {}

for line in text_line:
    one_line = line.split(maxsplit=1)   # <-- remove the ' '
    if len(one_line) > 1:
        acro = one_line[0].strip()
        meaning = one_line[1].strip()

        if acro in acronyms_dict:
            acronyms_dict[acro] = acronyms_dict[acro] + ", " + meaning
        else:
            acronyms_dict[acro] = meaning

print(acronyms_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
{
 '24KHGE': '24 Karat Heavy Gold Electroplate', 
 '2B1Q': '2 Binary 1 Quaternary', 
 '2D': '2-Dimensional', 

...
```